# Working in svnx with svn+ssh

Tags: svn, ssh, repository, version

I usually work with the mac program for subversion "svnx", and works rather well with http repositories. Today I tried to checkout a svn+ssh repo but the program does not work correctly. Somebody solved this problem?

Thanks

Comment: ok I realized that the trick is to use the program "Versions" for mac, which works much better than svnx in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found three things that have helped me use SvnX with svn+ssh repositories. These might help with your problem:

- do the initial checkout from the command line; this allows you to accept the site's host key
- older versions of subversion do not pass the -q option to ssh by default; if this is the case for you, add a line like this to the [tunnels] section of ~/.subversion/config:

  ssh = $SVN_SSH ssh -q
- if you use the ControlMaster option with ssh, you should disable it for svn; add a line like this to the [tunnels] section of ~/.subversion/config (you may need to combine this with the last item):

  ssh = $SVN_SSH ssh -o ControlMaster=no

Hope this helps!